# WPF Databound Label Design Time Text

Tags: wpf

I am playing about with WPF and databinding a Label control's content:

```
<Label Content="{Binding Name}" />
```

This works a treat, however I'd like to get some text in there at design time so I can see the label. Anyone know how to do this, seems it should be simple.

Thanks

TJ

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try this:

```
<Label Content="{Binding Name, FallbackValue='Text'}" />
```

Comment: @TomJohn: So it would be fine, if you accept this as the answer - so the question can be marked as resolved.

Comment: Not sure this is ok. If you have a binding error at runtime it will display this text (intended for design time).